# Powershell .ps1 scripts won't run / don't exist?

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I’ve started having the strangest problem with running powershell scripts in the last few weeks…

They all display this error message as if the file doesn’t exist?

Full console output below showing that I proved the file does exist with the Get-Content cmdlet…

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS H:\> C:
PS C:\> cd C:\Users\Public
PS C:\Users\Public> .\test3.ps1
.\test3.ps1 : The term '.\test3.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ .\test3.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.\test3.ps1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\Users\Public> get-content test3.ps1
Get-Process | Out-GridView -Wait

PS C:\Users\Public> .\test3.ps1
.\test3.ps1 : The term '.\test3.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ .\test3.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.\test3.ps1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\Users\Public>
```

I’ve already got my execution policy set to unrestricted.

Any suggestions

OS
Windows 10 Enterprise
Version 1909 (OS Build 18363.959)

```
PS C:\Users\Public>> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.18362.752
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.18362.752
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

**UPDATE:**

I can get a different result when set to run in PowerShell version 2...

```
PS C:\Users\Public> powershell -version 2 -ExecutionPolicy bypass -file test3.ps1
Out-GridView : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Wait'.
At C:\Users\Public\test3.ps1:1 char:33
+ Get-Process | Out-GridView -Wait <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Out-GridView], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutGridViewCommand

PS C:\Users\Public> powershell -version 3 -ExecutionPolicy bypass -file test3.ps1
The term 'C:\Users\Public\test3.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\Public\test3.ps1:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordExceptio
   n
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\Users\Public>
```

Presumably the -Wait argument just wasn't available in version 2.  I can use this now to run scripts in version 2, but obviously that's quite limited functionality.

**UPDATE 2:**

I had completely forgot that I had this exact problem earlier in the year; and even posted a Question about it over on Superuser…
https://superuser.com/questions/1536086/powershell-wont-run-ps1-files

I had marked up an answer that I thought it was caused by the transition from using CAG to CheckPointVPN (back in March when remote-working was becoming a long-term thing); and it was somehow resolved after going into the office and connecting directly to the network?

This time however; connecting directly to the office network isn’t resolving it.

Only thing else like that that has changed recently; was that IT setup support for Windows Password 30 day resets when working remotely (previously it wasn’t working, so the 30 day reset was previously disabled during lockdown).  I had reset my password remotely just before taking leave in August, and when I came back I was unable to run powershell scripts?

I have tried resetting my password while in the office, but it hasn’t fixed the problem.

I’m stuck for what else I can check??

Comment: Does it work if you use a fully qualified path?

Comment: Does `Get-Item .\test3.ps1 |% FullName` return `C:\users\public\test3.ps1`?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen yes, it returns exactly that

Comment: @OwlsSleeping no, same result, except for that the error message displays the full path

Comment: If you enter a session with no profile loaded, is it the same experience? `powershell -noprofile`

Comment: @codaamok using -noprofile doesn't alter the results

Comment: Does `. .\test3.ps1` or `& .\test3.ps1`  or `& ".\test3.ps1"` work?

Comment: @JosefZ tried all those too.  No joy

Comment: Can you include `$PSVersionTable` and current OS build (as shown in `winver`) in your question please?

Comment: @codaamok question updated now

Comment: Maybe try installing the latest cumulative update, see what happens. I notice you're just a couple of months out of date. A shot in the dark if I'm honest.

Comment: @codaamok its a work PC; I don't have that freedom

Comment: @codaamok I tried on a lower version of PowerShell, and it runs!?  Results added to question

Comment: Try moving the script file(s) to a different location and specify the full path. There may be a restriction enforced by Group Policy on running scripts from C:\Users\Public. Perhaps also, your antivirus application is blocking access to script files. In that case, you could try to add an exception for .ps1 scripts.

Comment: @Theo tried various locations; all have same result.  I've run `gpresult user /v` on both mine and a colleagues machine whose does work; and there is no synificant different in group policy settings.  Firewall settings are tricky for me to check, I can ask IT next time they respond to my open ticket, but I wouldnt suspect mine settings would be any different to my colleage's whose does work.  Thanks for the suggestions

Comment: Verify that you turned on the 'File name extensions' checkbox in the explorer, so you can make sure that there isn't a .txt behind your file (test3.ps1.txt).

Comment: @Pba always have it on :)

Comment: You could try running `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth` in an elevated command prompt, followed by `sfc /scannow` to repair all Windows OS system files.

Comment: @Skytunnel If you right click on test3.ps1, do you still get the suggestion to "Run with PowerShell" in the context menu? If so, does it work?

Comment: @Theo will try this as soon as I can get someone with admin rights to agree to it.  Thanks

Comment: @Thomas right-click and run with power pops up then disappears. Hence why I used the shell to show the error

Comment: Great, please let us know if that helped or not. (p.s. both commands can take a lot of time, so don't do this if you're in a hurry..)

Comment: Did you try adding the location of the ps files in @PATH and can you prove the file is there, using a simple DIR command in PowerShell?

Comment: Have you set execution policy to unrestricted for both 32-bit and 64-bit mode?

Comment: @Fandango68 DIR showed the file exists too. adding the folder to PATH yields the same result

Comment: @l33t tried both PowerShell (x86) and the normal 64-bit version.  Same result on each

Comment: Will any `.ps1` give you this error. E.g. some hello world script?

Comment: @l33t yes, any script.  A simpe `Write-Output "hello, world"` has the same error

Comment: Could it be that you are in fact on a network path? I doubt Windows will allow running scripts from remote locations.

Comment: @l33t I started on a network path and moved to C drive due to this error to test it wasnt a network issue

Comment: Well, I don't think your C drive path is a *real* path. Hence my question. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/244572/273872).

Comment: @l33t I'm aware of the difference between the two.  I specifically use the public users folder for tests like this because the normal document folders are sync'd to a server as that answer describes.

Answer (score 0):

In order not to let this question go by without answer, here my comment as answer

Seeing what you have already tried, I think there is a problem with one of the dll's in your system. Since PowerShell is part of Windows 10, you cannot uninstall/reinstall it as far as I know.

What you can try is to repair missing or corrupted system files.

Open an elevated command prompt and run

```
dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth
```

This will use Windows Update to provide the files that are required to fix corruptions, so an internet connection is required. If that is out of the question, you can specify another source with switch
`/Source:<PathToFreshWindowsFiles>`

When that finishes, type

```
sfc /scannow
```

to scan all protected system files, and replace corrupted files with a cached copy that is located in a compressed folder "%WinDir%\System32\dllcache"

Both actions take quite some time to finish.

When done reboot your computer.

Comment: Thanks.  Still trying to get an admin to do this, but found this regarding reinstalling PowerShell, so might get them to try it first... https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/reinstall-powershell/9012f88a-e154-4fa1-a556-763120508ce1

Comment: @Skytunnel It is definitively worth a try, but I'm not sure disableing and re-enableing the PowerShell freature fixes dll's. Really interested to hear how thing work out.

Comment: sorry for the delay; I have escalated the ticket, but still waiting for someone to help me.

Comment: Finally got IT support to look at this!.. They were able to run scripts when PowerShell was started as an admin from my machine; which proved it to be a permissions issue. Also identified an event log from the very date this problem started happening showing 14 changes to group policy.  So now the task of identifing which change it was; but sounds likes going to take some time.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was down to AppLocker preventing the script from running.

In order to check if this is the cause for your problem, open the Event Viewer and navigate to

```
> Applications and Services Logs
> > Windows
> > > AppLocker
> > > > MSI and Script
```

Look for any Error log entries and it should state something like

```
%OSDRIVE%\USERS\PUBLIC\TEST3.PS1 was prevented from running.
```

In my case this change was applied by IT security 2 months back; and since then the IT helpdesk have been slowly dealing with the complaints and whitelisting selected folder directories to resolve.

For some reason my colleagues weren't impacted by the change when they should have been; which lead me to believe it was a problem with my machine or user.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had this error and the issue was a file the script was trying to access did not exist.  I ran the script in powershell_ise.exe and clicked the Run Script button and a much clearer message was displayed:

Cannot find path 'C:\logs\logfile.log' because it does not exist.

I created the file and the script ran successfully.